# SQL ignore rows based on other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

On Microsoft SQL I run a query that will return tons of rows with a name and a state (plus lots of other columns), like so:

```
Name  | State   
------|------------    
Bob   | In Progress  
Bob   | In Progress
Sally | Complete      
Sally | Not Started
Sally | In Progress  
Bob   | Not Started
```

Every row will have one of those three states, and the rows may appear in any order.  More annoyingly, rows may repeat. If somebody is 'In Progress' then I don't want to see any rows for them of 'Not Started', and if they are 'Complete' then I don't want to see 'In Progress' or 'Not Started'.

So for the above data I'd just want to see

```
Name  | State   
------|------------    
Bob   | In Progress  
Sally | Complete
```

Is this possible with a SQL query?

Here's the actual query I'm using right now, but I still get entries where the name appears with more than one state.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want the "maximum" state.  Here is one method:

```
select name, state
from (select name, state
             row_number() over (partition by name
                                order by (case when State = 'Not Started' then 1
                                               when State = 'In Progress' then 2
                                               when State = 'Complete' then 3
                                               else 0
                                          end) desc
                                ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```